# Sitemap of SharePoint Online portal and all related content needed

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-contents

I've got a legal request for a list of ALL the SharePoint sites AND all the links/content listing from the SharePoint sites. The site export from the Admin portal is not adequate. Is it possible within the Admin realm of SharePoint Online?  If not, is there a tool that can be recommended that will do this for me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you hoping to find information on all site sets including sub-sites of each site set?
If so, you can use PowerShell to export these sites information.

For the first method, you can [download the PnP module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/2.2.0) and then refer to the PowerShell command in this article: [Get All Sites and Sub Sites in SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/10/get-all-sites-and-sub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-using-pnp-powershell.html).

Second method, We can create a [SharePoint Site Collections and Subsites Inventory Report](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-site-collections-subsites-report.html).

I hope this will help you.